# How do I determine if a subset of a function space is open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Specifically,C[0,1] represents the set of real valued functions that are continuous in the domain [0,1] and set A, subset of C[0,1],is the set of all strictly positive continuous functions in [0,1]. Is A open or closed? The norm defined over the space is the infinite norm, max{|f(x)|}.

I have always used the open ball/epsilon neighborhood concept for Euclidean spaces. How do I use it for function spaces? Using the infinite norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is not closed: consider the constant functions $f_n(x)=1/n>0$ for all $x$. Then $f_n\to 0$ in $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm but clearly $0\not\in A$.

$A$ is open: Let $f\in A$. Then $m=\inf_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)>0$ since $f$ achieves its minimum, being continuous on $[0,1]$. Then $B(f,m/2):=\{g\in C[0,1]:\|g-f\|<m/2\}$ (open ball centered at $f$ with radius $m/2$) is contained in $A$: $\|g-f\|<m/2 \implies -m/2<g-f<m/2 \implies f-m/2<g<f+m/2$, so $$\inf_{x\in [0,1]} g(x)\ge \inf_{x\in [0,1]} f(x) - m/2 = m-m/2=m/2>0$$ so that $g>0$